# Error with deploying springboot app to heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, github, heroku

I am deploying with git. I am using [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). When I input the command `git push heroku main`, it starts building, downloading somethings then after sometime, I get the error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project assessment: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]`

and also:

```
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ----
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version ----
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to app.
```

I created a new branch and added the project to it and tried to push to that branch with `git push heroku <branchname>:main`, but it sill does not work. I have got the same error.

```
<build>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/>


<!--    ...   -->

<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I started with the springboot demo project with, with mongodb, web and lambok dependencies.

It is just a very basic app that is working.

Comment: Sorry for the probably stupid question, but when you say you're running `git push heroku <branchname>:main` do you mean literally that or did you replace `<branchname>` with the name of your branch?

Comment: What version of Java is running on Heroku?

Comment: I didn't use <branchname> I used the name of the branch I created.
Springboot version 2.7.3

Comment: When asking questions, please always include _complete_ error messages. There's a bunch of helpful stuff that should be above this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means maven uses different java version.

Heroku uses OpenJdk8 by default- if you are using different version you need to specify the required version in `system.properties` file. Something like:

```
java.runtime.version=17
```

Here are more details from Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions

Comment: I just added that and I am getting a new error: `remote: ! Your account has reached its concurrent builds limit.` fixed it with `heroku restart`. 
Thank you!